# Insert query: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, default

This is a table that auto increments the ID, takes the time input, and sets the default of the total column as zero and the date column with `getdate()`

```
CREATE TABLE OrderPlaced (
    OrderID bigint IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    PlacedAt time NOT NULL,
    PlacedOn DATE NOT NULL default getdate(),
    Total MONEY default 0
)
```

So the only value that I have to insert is the time.

```
insert into OrderPlaced values ('13:40');
```

However on insertion SQL Server gives me this error:

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the column name as well, like this:

`INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...) VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);`

So it will be like this:

`insert into OrderPlaced values ('13:40');`

Answer (score 2):

The error *is* telling you the problem. Your table, `OrderPlaced`, has **four** columns, but you only supply *one* column in the `INSERT` and don't tell the instance what column to insert it into.

For your table, if you don't specify the columns then it will expect values for `PlacedAt`, `PlacedOn` and `Total`; it won't expect a value for `OrderID` as it is an `IDENTITY` and you haven't turned on `IDENTITY_INSERT`. As the instance is expecting 3 columns, and you only provide one, you get an error telling you that the number of columns don't match (3 != 1).

If you only want to insert a value into `PlacedAt`, and allow the rest of the columns use their `DEFAULT` values then define in your `INSERT` clause you only want to provide a value for `PlacedAt`:

```sql
INSERT INTO dbo.OrderPlaced(PlacedAt)
VALUES ('13:40');
```

Or, if you are (oddly) opposed to defining the columns in the `INSERT` clause, then tell the instance that the other 2 columns need their `DEFAULT` values.

```sql
INSERT INTO dbo.OrderPlaced
VALUES ('13:40',DEFAULT, DEFAULT);
```

Though I don't recommend this solution, be explicit as then if you change definition of the table, the above statement will fail.

Comment: can you also help me here? the original statement for placed at was PlacetAt time Default convert(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 108), and i dont know how to call it since i will then insert no values?

Comment: I don't follow what you're asking there @HSaad , but if you have a new question, [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).